# How do I get input for file streams correctly using a function with pointer and string parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

I am working on a file assignment for C++ and am having a difficult time distinguishing the test code in main, from what I'm supposed to have my logic doing in my functions. For instance, I need to implement the function:

Here is the code I'm using to test with:

```
int main()
{
    std::string filename = "cars.txt";
    std::ifstream fin;
    bool isOpen = GetInputFileStream(&fin, filename);
    if (isOpen == false)
    {
        std::cout << "Couldn't find file " << filename << "!" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        double newTotalPrice = 0;
        double newTotalMileage = 0;
        double usedTotalPrice = 0;
        double usedTotalMileage = 0;
        int numUsed = 0;
        int numNew = 0;

        AnalyzeFile(fin, numUsed, numNew, newTotalPrice, newTotalMileage,
            usedTotalPrice, usedTotalMileage);
        PrintStatistics(std::cout, numUsed, numNew, newTotalPrice, newTotalMileage,
            usedTotalPrice, usedTotalMileage);
    }
}
```

Here is the function (one of many) I need to implement:

```
bool GetInputFileStream(std::ifstream * fin, std::string filename)
{

}
```

The caller will supply a pointer to an input file stream object. I will use this object to open an input file that has
the name `filename`. If the file doesn’t exist, alert the user by returning `false`.

Comment: You have to post real code. not just typed code.

Comment: This seems like a bad design.  You should either  ask for a file name and make your own stream or you accept a reference to a stream and read from it.

Comment: I'm sure you meant `bool GetInputFileStream(std::ifstream& is, std::string filename)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before use any stream file you should check if the file exist and it can be done with function `_stat`:

```
bool existFile(string path)
{
    struct _stat attributos;
    int rstat;

    rstat = _stat(path.c_str(), &attributos);

    if (rstat == 0)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

> For Unix/Linux use the header `#include <sys/stat.h>`
>
> For Windows use the header `#include <windows.h>`

And, as @dlasalle recommend you, use the function `open(..)` to get the file stream (`ifstream`) and do I\O operations, for example:

```
ifstream f;
f.open("c:\..\file", ios::out | ios::app); 

if (f.is_open()) {
  // Do anything
}
```

So, you function could be this:

```
bool GetInputFileStream(std::ifstream& fin, std::string filename)
{
  bool eFile = existFile(filename);

  if(eFile)
  {
    fin.open(filename, ios::in);
  }
  return eFile;
}
```

Check that I change the parameter `std::ifstream* fin` to `std::ifstream& fin`, that's meaning you must invoke your function as:

```
std::ifstream fin;
bool isOpen = GetInputFileStream(fin, filename);
```

**UPDATE**: Answering your question:

```
ifstream* GetInputFileStream(bool& eFile, string filename)
{
  ifstream* fin = NULL;
  eFile = existFile(filename);

  if(eFile)
  {
    fin = new ifstream();
    fin->open(filename, ios::in);
  }
  return fin;
}
```

And you can get the pointer to `ifstream` in this way:

```
bool bExist;
string path;
ifstream* fin = GetInputFileStream(bExist, path);
```

Comment: There is a pointer version of code to pass to these particular parameters. Ill post the code in a second for accuracy but instead of fin.open you would use fin->open.

Comment: @MetatronYHVH, I made an upgrade.

Comment: I don't believe I can alter the function signature at all. My next question is by using NULL there, do this replicate the effect of a void function?

Comment: No, i'm using NULL to initialize the pointer to ifstream. The function always will return a pointer, no mater if it has an instance or not (represented by Null). A `void` return type means that the function will not return anything.

Comment: Ah, I forgot you must initialize a point to something even if it's NULL. I cannot use ifstream::good() either.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use some platform specific code ([`access()` in `unistd.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/access.html) for unix systems) to tell if the file exists, or just assume if you fail to open it, it does not exist (see [`std::ifstream::good()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/good/)).

See the documentation of [`std::ifstream::open()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/open/):

> void open (const   char* filename,  ios_base::openmode mode =
>   ios_base::in);
>
> void open (const string& filename,  ios_base::openmode
>   mode = ios_base::in);

The second function is only available in C++11.

So, if you don't care about why the file failed to open:

```
fin->open(filename);
return fin->good();
```